# How to insert multiple properites with same name but different values in neo4j relation?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have 2 nodes, person and job.The relation between them is VIEWED.
I need to store the list of timestamps the person viewed the job in the properties of VIEWED relation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use additional nodes (with label `:Viewing)` with a relationship to the `:Person` and the  `:Job` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

With Cypher, you can use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) to ensure that only a single `VIEWED` relationship exists between a `Person` and `Job` pair, and the `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH` clauses to either initialize or append to the relationship's timestamp list.

For example:

```
MATCH (p:Person), (j:Job)
WHERE p.id = 123 AND j.id = 987
MERGE (p)-[r:VIEWED]->(j)
ON CREATE SET r.times = [datetime()]
ON MATCH SET r.times = r.times + datetime()
```